# Why is this logo not being rendered by Wicket?

Tags: java, css, wicket

I have a `BasePage.java` (together with a `BasePage.html`). My base page is basically a CSS menu made by `mycssmenu.com` (I'm not good with CSS). I want to add my university's logo to the base page:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="MainPage.html"wicket:id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="LecturerPage.html"wicket:id="lect">Lecturer Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="StudentPage.html"wicket:id="stud">Student Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="qmdivider qmdividery" ></span></li>
    <li><a class="qmparent" href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="About.html"wicket:id="about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="qmclear">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">qm_create(0,false,0,500,false,false,false,false,false</script>
</div>
<div id= "body">
    <img src="C:\Users\Eliezer Shindler\Desktop\cityunilogo.jpg"alt="City Logo"/>
    <wicket:child />
```

In short, the City logo gets displayed when I open the page in a web browser, but not when running Wicket. Why, and how can I make it work with Wicket? I'm quite new to Wicket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referencing a local drive path (`C:\...`), which: a) will not work outside your machine; b) even if it worked, the browser won't show it, due security restrictions (will only open local files if the original page is also loaded from disk).

Don't, **ever**, use local machine paths in a web application. Just don't, it's evil, and your descendants will be cursed for 7 generations.

If you want an image to be displayed in your web application, move it into a folder inside your application context, or in the classpath, and make your page point there.

Suppose your project layout is like this:

```
myapp/
    src/
        myapp/
            MyApplication.java
            MyPage.java
            MyPage.html
    web/
        WEB-INF/
            web.xml
```

You could create a `myapp/web/images` folder, and copy your image (say, `logo.png`) into it:

```
myapp/
    src/
        myapp/
            MyApplication.java
            MyPage.java
            MyPage.html
    web/
        images/
            logo.png
        WEB-INF/
            web.xml
```

In `MyPage.html`, the markup would be something like this:

```
<img src="images/logo.png">
```

Another approach is to add your images from Java code, keeping your images/resources side-by-side with your `.java` files:

```
myapp/
    src/
        myapp/
            images/
                logo.png
            MyApplication.java
            MyPage.java
            MyPage.html
    web/
        WEB-INF/
            web.xml
```

Then, the declaration in `MyPage.html` would be

```
<img wicket:id="logo">
```

And `MyPage.java` would contain

```
add(new Image("logo", new PackageResourceReference(HomePage.class, "images/logo.png")));
```

meaning that the `logo.png` file is in a 'images' folder, relative to the `HomePage` class' package.

A similar approach (using header contributions instead of `Image`) can be used for CSS and javascript files.

This is a lot more verbose, but can be very useful, especially if you modularize the reusable components into a library, since you can then bundle all resources (images, css and javascript files, etc.) into one jar.

Comment: @tetsou -thank you-I did it the first way-see my answer below about creating an images folder(in 'context') and putting the jpg in there